# New Chamberlain garage door opener belt is too short. How to fix this problem?

Tags: doors, garage

I purchased a chamberlain garage door belt. Could not install, it's one and a half inches too short. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's too short? Belt-driven units often have a tensioner that may be installed incorrectly. I'd be surprised that they have belts of varying sizes that are so close in length.

Comment: Have you contacted Chamberlain customer service to see what they say? What does the installation manual say about it?

Answer (score 4):

Typically that is because you dont have the rails all the way together. I have installed 500+ chamberlain belt drive units, and have never had a belt too short.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you.

1. return it and get the right length.
2. move the motor housing mount by required distance assuming you have adjustable mount.

Answer (score 0):

I literally had the same exact problem. I was about a 1/4" from the trolley. Ensure all the railings are in as far as they can go before doing this.

If you have the railing installed on the motor, take out the bolt from the motor that you have to screw in out and let the railing sit in the stud that goes through the U bracket. Angle the motor slightly to get max tension on the belt. Make sure your belt isn't twisted and seated properly. You should now haveOnce you have the threaded shaft through the trolley bracket, screw on the tensioner spring just enough so that it doesn't slide out. Then rotate the motor until the hole aligns and reinsert the screw.